# How to save checkpoints of quantise wrapped models in tensorflow model optimization?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tfmot

Hi I am using tensorflow and model optimisations.

This is an overview of the process:

```
from tensorflow_model_optimization.quantization.keras import quantise_model
model = define_model()
qat_model = quantize_model(model)
qat_model.fit(...)
qat_model.save_weights("qat_weights.h5")
... Finish for Now ...
```

On another run

```
model = define_model()
qat_model = quantize_model(model)
qat_model.load_weights("qat_weights.h5")
```

But when I go to `qat_model.fit(...)` it has to start training again from 0%

So there must be a problem with either saving or loading of the weights

Answer (score 0):

After replicating the issue on given code, I observed that you need to compile the model after loading the weights and restart the training.

This way it's starting the model training at the same metrics state where the last model weights were saved.

Fixed code for saving weights:

```
from tensorflow_model_optimization.quantization.keras import quantize_model
model = define_model()
qat_model = quantize_model(model)
qat_model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),metrics=['accuracy'])
qat_model.fit(train_images, train_labels, batch_size=500, epochs=5, validation_split=0.1)
qat_model.save_weights("qat_weights.h5")
#... Finish for Now ...
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/5
108/108 [==============================] - 5s 13ms/step - loss: 0.9011 - accuracy: 0.7930 - val_loss: 0.2947 - val_accuracy: 0.9210
Epoch 2/5
108/108 [==============================] - 1s 10ms/step - loss: 0.3039 - accuracy: 0.9148 - val_loss: 0.2106 - val_accuracy: 0.9437
Epoch 3/5
108/108 [==============================] - 1s 11ms/step - loss: 0.2338 - accuracy: 0.9336 - val_loss: 0.1700 - val_accuracy: 0.9568
Epoch 4/5
108/108 [==============================] - 1s 11ms/step - loss: 0.1905 - accuracy: 0.9460 - val_loss: 0.1425 - val_accuracy: 0.9630
Epoch 5/5
108/108 [==============================] - 1s 9ms/step - loss: 0.1609 - accuracy: 0.9549 - val_loss: 0.1250 - val_accuracy: 0.9665
```

Fixed code for loading the weights:

```
model = define_model()
qat_model = quantize_model(model)
qat_model.load_weights("qat_weights.h5")
qat_model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),metrics=['accuracy'])
qat_model.fit(train_images, train_labels, batch_size=500, epochs=5, validation_split=0.1)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/5
108/108 [==============================] - 2s 10ms/step - loss: 0.1375 - accuracy: 0.9614 - val_loss: 0.1087 - val_accuracy: 0.9708
Epoch 2/5
108/108 [==============================] - 1s 7ms/step - loss: 0.1176 - accuracy: 0.9672 - val_loss: 0.0957 - val_accuracy: 0.9762
Epoch 3/5
108/108 [==============================] - 1s 7ms/step - loss: 0.1038 - accuracy: 0.9711 - val_loss: 0.0868 - val_accuracy: 0.9775
Epoch 4/5
108/108 [==============================] - 1s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0928 - accuracy: 0.9743 - val_loss: 0.0794 - val_accuracy: 0.9790
Epoch 5/5
108/108 [==============================] - 1s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0840 - accuracy: 0.9769 - val_loss: 0.0738 - val_accuracy: 0.9803
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7ff940090280>
```

(Attaching the replicated [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/508fa4e98047f8bbb3f453b64194013a/75139040.ipynb) here for your reference.)